# New to java stuck on Switch statement

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement

Hi I want to create a program by using switch statement where the user input for length should be within 1-100. If the user enters a value which is lees than 1 or greater than 100 then an error will be shown [System.out.println("Your number (" + Length + ") is not between 1-100. \nTry again.");]. The program I made is asking for an user input between 1-100 and its giving the output correct when I am entering the number 1 as number 1 is mentioned in case 1. But its not reading the condition that I have mentioned in case 1, when I am giving a different value to check whether the condition is working or not.

```js
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by MRIDULA on 27-12-2016.
 */
public class SwitchDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner length = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-100 for length: ");

        int lamba;
        lamba = length.nextInt();

        switch (lamba) {

            case 1: while ((lamba> 100) || (lamba <= 1)) {

                System.out.println("Great, your number for length is between 1 and 100");
            break;}

                case 2: System.out.println("Your number for length is not between 1-100. \nTry again.");
                    break;

                default: System.out.println("Invalid number.\nTry again.");
            }
        }
    }
```

. Can someone tell me what needs to be done to get the desired result in the below mentioned program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be using switch correctly here:

Your code got length from the user, got an int from that string and then passed it to switch here.

```
switch(lamba) {
    case 1: while ((lamba> 100) || (lamba <= 1)) {
```

In that situation, if lamba should be equal "1" for this condition to occur. Values from 2-100 will not work. Your while look is also noop, it should never run as lamba will never be equal to 1 and greater than 100 or <= 1 at the same time.

---

Also, switch is not the best tool for this problem. Switch is ideal when you have a finite number of fixed states to compare (command line switches might be a good example), and isn't ideal for comparisons of a range of numbers like this (greater or less than).

You should use an if/elsif/else statement. Something like the following.

```
if (((lamba> 100) || (lamba <= 1))) {
    System.out.println("Great, your number for length is between 1 and 100");
else {
    System.out.println("Your number for length is not between 1-100. \nTry again.");
}
```

Now, I want to add, you could do this (albeit it's not pretty). But, doing this is only going to convolute your code and make understanding the code's intent difficult.

```
if (lamba > 100) {
    lamba = 101;
}
if (lamba < 1) {
    lamba = 0;
}
switch (lamba) {
    case 0:
    case 101:
        System.out.println("Your number for length is not between 1-100. \nTry again.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Great, your number for length is between 1 and 100");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...!! :-)